# Search by user.name on Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a list of people names and want to find out if they have Twitter accounts, unreliable as that may be. How can I do it on Tweepy?

I am trying to pass user.name as an argument for the query, but it just seems to allow for searching their screen_names or ids.

```
user = api.get_user(screen_name='georgetakei')
print(user.name)
**> George Takei**
```

But if I try the other way round...

```
user = api.get_user(name='George Takei')
print(user.screen_name)
**> TweepError: [{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]**
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use the `api.search_users()` method?

Example using a list

```
#Search for users by name
name = 'George Takei'
users = api.search_users(q=name)

#Print the screen_name of the first matching user
if len(users) > 0:
    print(users[0].screen_name)
else:
    print("No user found with that name.")
```

Not 100% sure, but I think `api.search_users(q, count)` should work as well. As in `q` being query and `count` being the number of users to be retrieved

Comment: @MarceloSoares Tell me if you need any more help and if you get it working with the solution.

Comment: I am adapting your snippet to get more from it. It's really clever, thank you.

Comment: All right, happy coding!